# Click event for dynamically created labels VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

For college, I am creating a gravitational field simulator where two masses are shown along with the magnitude and direction of the gravitational force that they will experience. For the bodies of mass I am using dynamically created ovalshapes, and these ovalshapes each have a label on it showing the mass. These ovalshapes and labels are stored in a listarray.

I will need to be able to drag and drop these bodies. For the ovalshapes I am using `If OvalShape.ContainsFocus` but due to the fact that the labels will be ontop of these ovalshapes I need some sort of way to test whether the mouse is down on the labels. I have tried using an event handler but I get an error "click is not an event of system.collections.listarray" for this code `AddHandler labelArray.Click, AddressOf Me.labelArray_Click`

So my questions is, *Is there a ways to test whether a label belonging to a listarray has been clicked and which label within the array has been clicked on.* Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to hook the handler to one of the controls *inside* the array

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: are you sure that error msg is right?  `listarray` not `ArrayList`?  add the handler when you create the Label

Comment: yeah sorry, 'ArrayList'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the event handler to each label in the array

```
For Each l As Label In labelArray
AddHandler l.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler
Next
```

Then in the handler function:

```
Private Sub myClickHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim clickedLabel As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label) ' Cast the sending object into a Label object
  ' then do whatever you want with the label such as get it's text and show it in a message box:
    MessageBox.Show("Label text Clicked was: " & clickedLabel.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, keep in mind when you add new labels to the array you will want to make sure you add the handler to their click event also.This code will only take care of the ones which are currently in the array.

Comment: so what do I do if I want to know what label from the array has been clicked on?

Comment: I tried to add it here as a comment, let me just add it to the answer.